# Textbox mandatory on clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view where add to electronic has 2 radiobuttons yes & no. And a submit button.When yes radiobutton is clicked. the quantity textbox should not be empty.but it can be empty if no radiobutton is clicked.This functionality should work when submit button is clicked with yes radiobutton is selected.any ideas?
MY VIEW:

```
 <HTML>
    <head>
    radio
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id=radio>
     Add to electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes"onclick="validate(_this)"id="yes"/>Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
    <label>Quantity</label><input type="text"size="25"name="dir"id="dir" required/> 
<button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</body>
<div>
<script src="~/Scripts/radiobuttonvalidation.js"></script>
</div>
</html>
```

im new to mvc and javascript help me with javascript code too.and the way i should link it with my view.
Javascript:

```
    function validate(_this) {
    if ($(_this).attr('id') == "yes") {
        $('#dir').attr('required');
        alert("Text Box required");
    }
    else {
        $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
        alert("Text Box not required");
    }
}
```

Comment: first, look into client side validation with jquery validate, next look into view models and set [Required] attribute to textbox, this will take care of validation when you click submit button in the form. Now search for ways when yes is clicked, enable textbox validation, when no is clicked, disabled textbox validation, i only point out the way you can do it, you should try something yourself first.

Comment: i tried using j query but it didnot validate the textbox

Comment: you have shown your html. Show the javascript code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#radio").submit(function() {
    if ($('#yes').is(':checked') && !$.trim($('#quantity').val())) {
      alert("Please input the quantity.");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id=radio>
                Add to electronic <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
                <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" size="25" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
                <button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how to link this javascript and radiobutton in view?

Comment: I think its better to add required attribute on changing the radio button.

Comment: You can create a new tag called <script> and put it near the end of the body.
i.e. ...</form><script> // your own javascript here // </script></body>...

Answer (score 1):

HTML `Required` attribute can be really helpful in such scenarios. 
Go through this [Link](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/html/using-html-required-attribute/) for more information.
Also, Check [Jquery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) if you need more customization.

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
    radio
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function validate(_this)
        {
           if($(_this).attr('id') == "yes")
            {
                $('#quantity').attr('required');
                alert("Text Box required");
             }
            else
             {
                 $('#quantity').removeAttr('required');
                 alert("Text Box not required");
             }
        }
        
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id=radio>
     Add to electronic  
     <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" onchange="validate(this)"/>Yes
     <input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" onchange="validate(this)"/>No<br />
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="text"size="25" name="quantity"id="quantity" required/> 
    <button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i done it bro.still i didnt get any result. when i click the insert button with yes radio button clicked nothing happens.my radio and button code:                              Add to electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" onchange="validate(_this)"/>Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" onchange="validate(_this)"/>No<br /><label>Direction/frequency</label><input type="text" size="25" style="height: 30px;" id="dir" name="dir" required />                                       <script src="~/Scripts/radiobuttonvalidation.js"></script>